# Feature Request: Ticket System and Wiki

Tags: feature-request

Request #1: Ticket System
I would like to have a ticket system to have people follow up my StackOverflow questions. So that people can know who is in charge of the question and take care of my needs.

Request #2: Wiki
It would be great to have different kinds of Wikis to provide best practices and information on various topics in programming.

Comment: For the future, you should only have 1 request per question so people can answer and vote based on the feature in the question.  Your #2 is fairly self explanatory, but can you explain #1 a bit more.  It really doesn't make a lot of sense.  What is the ticket for?  And why is someone "in charge" of your Stack Overflow question

Comment: I look forward to being your humble servant and taking care of your needs.

Answer (score 17):

You are missing the important point that no-one on SO is under any obligation to help you. That rules out your "Ticket System" idea. We are here to solve interesting problems and share knowledge. We are not here to "be in charge of" or "follow up on" your questions. Besides, there are comments to notify people of relevant changes.

As far as the "Wiki" idea goes... The entirety of StackOverflow is a wiki. The universal interface to that is a search engine. Nobody reads curated FAQs, especially not on a system where they can simply ask a concrete question. Besides, there *are* FAQs to various areas of programming on SO ([for example on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)). The fact that you've missed them proves my point.